# Laravel Attempt to read property "alias" on null

Tags: php, laravel

```php
Route::get('catalog/{catname}', [MainController::class, 'getCatalog'])->name('catalog.page');
Route::get('catalog/{catname}/{alias}', [MainController::class, 'getItemsForList'])->name('catalog.view.item');
```

When I click on the link /catalog/table/table-black-and-white, I get an error

```php
Attempt to read property "alias" on null
```

During development, I connected the database via belongsToMany

```php
\App\Models\Catalog

public function items() : BelongsToMany
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
}

\App\Models\Item
public function catalogs() : BelongsToMany
{
return $this->belongstoMany(Catalog::class);
}
```

The controller has two entries for outputting information

```php
public function getCatalog($alias)
    {
        $cats = Catalog::where('alias', $alias)->first();
        $cats->items;
        return view('template.sait.page.catalog', compact('cats'))->with('alias', $alias);
    }

    public function getItemsForList($alias)
    {
        $data = Item::where('alias', $alias)->with('catalogs')->first();
        return view('template.sait.page.catalog.view', compact('data'))->with('alias', $alias);
    }
```

And in the view I display it like this:

```php
@foreach($cats->items as $item)
.....
.....
<a href="{{route(''catalog.view.item'', $item->alias)}}">env</a>
```

As far as I understand, there is an error in my controller, and apparently I also do not fully indicate the route in the view, since sometimes I still get the error of missing **“alias”** field.

**UPD 20.01.24:**
It seems that we managed to display all the data in their sections, there was a confusion with additional names, thanks to everyone for all kinds of help. But now a problem has arisen with the fact that when I go into an object, my address line changes to what I select, but the contents of the object remain unchanged.

```php
$item = Item::whereHas('catalogs', function ($catalogs) use($alias){
      $catalogs->where('alias', $alias);
    })->with('catalogs')
      ->firstOrFail();
    if (!$item){
      abort(404, 'Page Not found');
    }
dd($items);
```

That is, I’m now going to, say, the page:
`www/catalogs/table/table-red-white-color`, I get everything related to the red round table. But if in the same category I go to another link: `www/catalogs/table-blue-black-color` then information opens on the red table and not on the blue one, although in the address line there is a link to the blue table.

Comment: Are you sure `$alias` has value and `$cats` retuns data?

Comment: if `$cats = Catalog::where('alias', $alias)->first();` returns results, it doesnt necessarily means that `$data = Item::where('alias', $alias)->with('catalogs')->first();` will return any. maybe switch it to `firstOrFail()` to return a 404 or to `$data = Item::whereHas('catalogs', function ($catalog) { $catalog->where('alias', $alias);})->with('catalogs')->firstOrFail();`

Comment: what line is causing that error?

Answer (score 0):

The query didn't find a matching `Catalog` with the provided alias in the `getCatalog` method, this indicates that the `$cats` variable is `null` when trying to access the `alias` property.

Check if `$cats` is not `null` before accessing its properties.

```
public function getCatalog($alias)
{
    $cats = Catalog::where('alias', $alias)->first();

    if (!$cats) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $cats->load('items'); // I eager loaded the 'items' relationship here

    return view('template.sait.page.catalog', compact('cats'))->with('alias', $alias);
}
```

Update the `getItemsForList` method

```
public function getItemsForList($alias)
{
    $item = Item::where('alias', $alias)->with('catalogs')->first();

    if (!$item) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return view('template.sait.page.catalog.view', compact('item'))->with('alias', $alias);
}
```

Modify variable names accordingly in the view

```
@foreach($item->catalogs as $catalog)
    <a href="{{ route('catalog.view.item', ['catname' => $catalog->alias, 'alias' => $item->alias]) }}">env</a>
@endforeach
```

**NB:** The important things to note are you check if the `$cats` variable is not null, and if it is, you can choose to either `abort` with a `404` error or handle it differently.

**UPD 20.01.24:**
It seems that we managed to display all the data in their sections, there was a confusion with additional names, thanks to everyone for all kinds of help. But now a problem has arisen with the fact that when I go into an object, my address line changes to what I select, but the contents of the object remain unchanged.

```php
$item = Item::whereHas('catalogs', function ($catalogs) use($alias){
      $catalogs->where('alias', $alias);
    })->with('catalogs')
      ->firstOrFail();
    if (!$item){
      abort(404, 'Page Not found');
    }
dd($items);
```

That is, I’m now going to, say, the page:
`www/catalogs/table/table-red-white-color`, I get everything related to the red round table. But if in the same category I go to another link: `www/catalogs/table-blue-black-color` then information opens on the red table and not on the blue one, although in the address line there is a link to the blue table.

Comment: [AI-Generated answers are banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: @AbdullaNilam this is not AI-Generated, this is very basic Laravel process, I don't need AI to see the error

Comment: `App\Models\Catalog {#324 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\MainController.php:35` - $cats not null, @EnochOsarenren

Comment: @YuraLons do you still experience the same error or a different one?

Comment: @EnochOsarenren, The error is still the same - I tried both options that are in the suggestions, but he still swears

Comment: App\Models\Item::catalogs(): Return value must be of type App\Models\BelongsToMany, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany returned

Comment: @EnochOsarenren, I solved the problem by removing it from the line in the model `catalogs() : BelongsToMany {....}` just left it `catalogs() {.....}

Comment: @EnochOsarenren, But now I can’t get the fields in the item card, that is, nothing you

Comment: @EnochOsarenren, if I leave the first(), then a 404 error is displayed, but if I output via get(), then the page opens without an error, but I can’t get the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256583/discussion-between-yura-lons-and-enoch-osarenren).

Comment: @YuraLons you should read carefully the comment on your question. The alias field on the category is not the same as on your items so you cant get the results of one from the data of the other.

Comment: @N69S, How then can I get data on the subject? I tried what is described above, but the result is still empty

Comment: @YuraLons did using `whereHas` not work for you ?

Comment: @YuraLons the issue you're experiencing is not clear, what's the alias in your DB?

Comment: @EnochOsarenren, MySQL (DOCKER)

Comment: @N69S, Yes - `whereHas` doesn't work either.